# Clicking on tabs sometimes shows the wrong page

Tags: ionic3

I have an Ionic 3 project. I'm using lazyload navigation.

Sometimes I have a strange thing happen when  I click on one of my tabs, in the tabs navigation.

Instead of going to the root tab page, it goes to another page in the previous history. In other words, if I go to the a subpage of 'Contacts', then click on the 'Profile' tab, then click on the 'Contacts' tab. Instead of going to the main 'Contacts' page, it displays the 'Contacts' sub page I previously opened.

Here is what the control looks like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = 'ContactsPage';
  tab2Root = 'AlertsPage';
  tab3Root = 'SharePage';
  tab4Root = 'ProfilePage';
  tab5Root = 'SettingsPage'

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

and her is what the html looks like:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Contacts" tabIcon="ai-icon_contacts" class="theTab"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="Alerts" tabIcon="ai-icon_alerts"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="Share" tabIcon="ai-icon_share"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="Profile" tabIcon="ai-icon_profile"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab5Root" tabTitle="Settings" tabIcon="ai-icon_settings"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

How can I ensure that when I click on one of the tabs I'm going to and setting the root page for that tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by default. That means this is how the tabs and nav are expected to work. Read [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

If you want to view the root of a tab every time you select a tab, then do this:

In your `tabs.html`

```
<ion-tabs (ionChange)="tabChange($event)">
...
<ion-tabs>
```

In your `tabs.ts`

```
tabChange(ev){
    ev.setRoot(ev.root);
}
```

Comment: This does not work in Ionic 4. There is no `root` or `setRoot` in the event.